# Why does my html page get additional, unwanted, height on mobile safari?

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, safari

I have a web app which looks as expected on all devices/browsers except on Safari on iOS.
Below is the expected, full screen view, where it shouldn't be possible to scroll in y-direction.

[image: Expected behaviour]

As said, this works fine everywhere, except in Safari on iOS where I can scroll in y-direction about 50% of the viewport height:

[image: Unwanted behaviour]

I've inspecting all elements in the inspector and can find nothing that explains this behavior, seems almost like it's something outside of the rendering tree, like some iOS feature, that causes it since even inspecting the root html element (like below) just highlights the expected part of the view (the part highlighted in blue in the picture at the bottom).

If anyone has has seen this issue and knows a possible cause, pls let me know.

[image: web inspector]
[image: highlighed html root inspect]

Comment: I had something similar a while ago, where I've used `height: 100vh`. The height is set correct at first glance, but as soon as you stop interacting with the browser on iOS, the browser navigation disappears making the viewport larger. And somehow on safari this doesn't get updated. Maybe it's something similar?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer in right direction. I was fighting with the safari 100vh issue a lot earlier but completely forgot about it. It might be something related to this happening here too, although I've restricted use of vhs to bare minimum... will investigate more. Good link: https://allthingssmitty.com/2020/05/11/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/