# iOS Safari overriding 100vh on input focus: Injecting empty space below the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, safari

When an input field is selected on iOS Safari, about ≈150px is injected, outside of the DOM, below the HTML tag

[image]

In the screenshot above the green border has been applied to the HTML element - and the black scrollable area beneath is only accessible on iOS safari when an input field has been focused. While the HTML element retains its 100vh/svh attribute

You can see the `<HTML>` tag turn blue when I hover over the element in the console... I've done this to help show that the empty space is not related to the webpage itself

The expected functionality is for the keyboard not to inject this spacing below the keyboard… as is the case for other browsers on iOS

[image]

I've spent some time messing around with different height values (SVH is preferred in my instance) and overflow style settings, using JS and CSS, but none of that has an impact because the space added to the webpage appears to be independent of the DOM and inaccessible via the console

Specifically, I've experimented with calculating the actual viewport height when the page loads, and then using this fixed value throughout the lifetime of the page - by applying this fixed value to the body/html element to ensure that no extra space is added at the bottom when the keyboard is displayed

`CSS`

```
body {
  --vh: 100vh; /* Fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

`JS`

```
useEffect(() => {
  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
  
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
  });

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', () => {
      let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
    });
  };
}, []);
```

But since the space injected does not appear to be a part of the DOM - updating the height of the `<HTML>` or `<body>` tags does not actually resolve the issue.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

- [Code Sandbox (Code)](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-dew-fibs5k?file=/src/index.tsx)
- [Code Sandbox (Demo)](https://fibs5k.csb.app/)
- [Screen Recording](https://imgur.com/a/ZphP7Pg)
- [Another (unresolved) SO thread discussing the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122046/why-does-my-html-page-get-additional-unwanted-height-on-mobile-safari)

Comment: Please provide all your code to reproduce the issue!

Comment: @imhvost the code has already been provided? Please take a look at the links

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly this too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No…  but please follow up if you are able to make any progress!

Answer (score 1):

I tried fixing your css with the DevTools.
I managed to fix it via adding `box-sizing: border-box;`

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is not a replicable solution

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is update your html tag style with following code

```
html {
border: 5px solid green;
max-height: 100svh;
max-width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
overflow: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box; //Add this
```

}

and the second solution is give height 100vh - 10px and width 100vw - 10px because border is taking (5 + 5) pixels in width and height so reduce it from width and height use

```
html {
    border: 5px solid green;
    max-height: 100svh;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 10px); //reduce 10px from height (5px + 5px) border of top and bottom
    width: calc(100vw - 10px);  //reduce 10px from width (5px + 5px) border of left and right
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also give css property to textarea field

```
textarea {
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
resize: none;  //It will disable option to resize textarea by textarea bottom-right corner
}
```

Just try it and let me know if that its working or not
Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure how this is intended to act as a solution... Since the issue is not a result of a content overflow.

Have you tested the codepen on an iOS device?

If you would like to look - I've added the box-sizing suggestion to the code pen you and GTD suggested to show that it does not address the issue.

Comment: Try with give width and height to textarea field or html field

Comment: This is not a replicable solution. Please fork the codepen demo and test your suggestions

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend trying:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I don't know if it will work because I didn't see any actual html

Comment: What do you mean you didn’t see any actual HTML?

Comment: i dont see the html and i cant access the links

Comment: There’s no reason you shouldn’t be able to open the provided codepen links

Comment: website is blocked for me because it is for some reason counted as a proxi site